# AngularJS tutorial not binding data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very basic example that isn't working:  I have two aspects, the index.html and the main.js.  They are in the same folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title> AngularJS Tutorials </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.min.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {message: "Hello"};
}
```

my page shows this:

```
{{data.message}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the controller to the angular module. you can use the `controller` function to add the js function for your controller.

```
var FirstCtrl = function FirstCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {message: "Hello2"};
};

angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("FirstCtrl",FirstCtrl);
```

If you already had the angular module defined somewhere else in the page, Use this version.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("FirstCtrl",FirstCtrl);
```

Here is a working sample http://jsbin.com/tiroteharu/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

    myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.data = { message: "Hello" };
    }]);

</script>



<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <h1>{{data.message}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

More help read: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller